# What does property .t means on elixir?

Tags: elixir

For example in this typespec for module String:

```
@spec validate(String.t) :: {:atom}
```

What does it mean? and how can I test it through `iex`?

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function String.t/0 is undefined or private
    (elixir) String.t()
```

**Update**

Looks like some people dont see the necessity of testing which is the type of something through iex

For the rest of us who are learning elixir we can do it like this:

```
iex(8)> t String
@type t() :: binary()
@type codepoint() :: t()
@type grapheme() :: t()
@type pattern() :: t() | [t()] | :binary.cp()
iex(9)> t(String)
@type t() :: binary()
@type codepoint() :: t()
@type grapheme() :: t()
@type pattern() :: t() | [t()] | :binary.cp()
```

Also for the .t

> If you want to refer to the “string” type (the one operated on by
>   functions in the String module), use String.t/0 type instead.

source https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/typespecs.html#notes

Comment: It's a type, you don't need to test anything here.

Comment: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#t:t/0

Answer (score 4):

It's not a property. Basically it's a reference to “string” type which is being used by functions from Elixir's String module. To fully understand it please read more [here](http://elixir-lang.github.io/getting-started/typespecs-and-behaviours.html).

One reason for using `String.t()` is that Elixir [discourages the use of `string()`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/typespecs.html#the-string-type). A `string()` is a "charlist" in Elixir, while `String.t()` is a UTF-8 encoded binary.

Comment: This is the right link to the doc https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/typespecs.html#notes
If you want to refer to the “string” type (the one operated on by functions in the String module), use String.t/0 type instead.

Comment: One link leads to another - both are right. Isn't it what you were looking for?